# SQL : Check if primary key is foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I want to extract the **name of** primary key column of table if it is also foreign key from information schema 
like two tables :

```
Student 
std_id  std_name
```

And

```
PHDstudent
std_id   reaserchfield
```

That std_id in PHDstudent is primary key and foreign key at same time that refers to Student table.

Comment: If the PK is composite, do you need to detect both if *all* columns are part of an FK reference, and if individual columns (or a subset of all of the PK columns) are part of an FK reference?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: DBMS is sql server 2008. And i want name of column in phdstudent not in student table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query

```
SELECT Tab.TABLE_NAME, Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY '
INTERSECT
SELECT Tab.TABLE_NAME, Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'FOREIGN KEY '
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But what if want to get referenced table? I've added "select Tab.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME". But doesn’t answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.std_id FROM Student s 
INNER JOIN PHDstudent p 
ON s.std_id = p.std_id
```

Have a read on [INNER JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: In query the name of primary key is not known and i want to get column name from information_shcema

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about primary key column name, than you should go with below query which gives you the primary key column name.....

**`SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND table_name = 'PHDstudent'`**